# unable to Identify the window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I just started writing a first function using CodedUI for our desktop application. I am trying to verify whether window exists or not. I used `Exists` method for verifying the window existence. But I am getting exception like

```
"The following is not a valid technology name: MSAA. To search for a control, you must specify a valid technology name.\r\nParameter name: TechnologyName"}
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share your test code?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than verifying that a window exists, it is often more convenient to verify that the window contains a piece of text or a data-entry field or a button, etc. To find the text, or whatever, Coded UI must first find the containing window and the search properties used look for a specific window. They fail if the window is not found. Having found the window, Coded UI searches inside it for the required item. Thus a search for something in a window implicitly searches for the window.

I recommend using the Coded UI record and generate tool to create an assertion that some fixed text, or even the label on a button, on the window is present. Even if your goal is hand coded testing, use the record and generate tool in a sand box project to see how the test code can be generated and copy the useful parts into your own tests.

The `exists` method is, I believe, intended for checking on the contents of windows to see whether data dependant items have been displayed or not, including the case of items that should not be present.